# Regex with optional word inside string

Tags: regex, string, option-type, cpu-word

I try to Regex the following line (each word separated by one space):

```
Firstpartstring thisisoptional secondpartstring
```

I expect each string to match as group:

```
Group 1.    Firstpartstring
Group 2.    thisisoptional
Group 3.    secondpartstring
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
(.*?)\s(thisisoptional)?\s(.*)
```

Only problem is, if "thisisoptional" does not exist inside the string, I don't get any results.

I expect:

```
Group 1.    Firstpartstring
Group 2.    
Group 3.    secondpartstring
```

Please check this demo: https://regex101.com/r/YBlYXm/1

Can anyone get me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: The demo and what you tried are way different

Comment: Sorry, link is fixed now

Comment: is thisisoptional a constant character?

Comment: Your regex requires the whitespaces whereas you maybe wanted to make at least one of these optional as well?

Comment: unfortunately no, so a universal solution would be great

Comment: Yes correct Neil Coffey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are asking for two spaces (\s) in your Regex which does not match your case if thisisoptional is not included. The easy fix is to include the second space in your 2nd capturing group:

```
(.*?)\s(thisisoptional\s)?(.*)
```

this selects anything followed by thisisoptional then followed by anything

Comment: Thank you. I use this one :)

Comment: Keep in mind that with this answer, the second group always captures a trailing space, which may not necessarily be what you want.

Comment: indeed, depending on what you're trying to do exactly, you may need to play around with more/less spaces at the end ot in the middle according to your format. Just something to keep in mind as you go

Answer (score 2):

The space before the optional word should be made optional as well; otherwise it would require two spaces between the first and the last word to match:

```
(.*?)(?:\s(thisisoptional))?\s(.*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/YBlYXm/2

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just group all non-whitespace characters with `(\S+)` and then remove the middle one if you get three matches?

Example of this regex running: https://regex101.com/r/IIyM5Z/1